# cannot create custom ant design icon component from a svg file

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the icon I want to use in svg format stored in assets folder. I am importing that file and then create a component for the custom icon as shown below:

```
import dateIcon from "../../../assets/images/icons/calendar_blue.svg";
const calendarIcon = () => <img src={dateIcon} />;
```

And then when I want to use it as a suffix or prefix I use it as:

```
<Icon component={calendarIcon} />
```

I get a typescript error: "TypeScript error in "MYFILE".tsx(27,27):
')' expected.  TS1005

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SVG directly inside Icon. You have to convert it into jsx.

1. Convert the SVG Icon into the function.Use [this](https://react-svgr.com/playground/) website to convert SVG to function.
   let's say function is Abc
2. Now use that function inside Icon  `<Icon component={Abc} />`.
   Your Icon is ready to use.If you still face any issue please comment.